# array_push replacing value instead of adding new value in array

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a cart system, which is I need to sum all total product. I'm thinking about saving the total to an array, so I can use `array_sum` it later. But somehow the array `$total_cart[]` only have last total, for example is if I have three product in my cart, the total saved in the array is only from the third not all product that I have.  And the total value is from calculation `$price_discount * $cart_item['quantity'];`

```
foreach ($cart_decode as $key => $cart_item):
    $product = \App\Models\Product::where('id', $cart_item['product_id'])->first();
    $discount = ($product->price * $product->discount) / 100;
    $price_discount = $product->price - $discount;

    $total_cart = array();
    $total_cart[] = $price_discount * $cart_item['quantity'];
endforeach
```

Comment: It's because you reset the array on every iteration. Move `$total_cart = array();` outside the foreach loop

Comment: @marco-a ah! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$total_cart = array();` is in a loop so it reset every time.

You should put `$total_cart = array();` before foreach.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it's working correctly

Answer (score 3):

Your code creates/defines a new array in every single loop. You should define  `$total_cart` before the looping/foreach.

```
$total_cart = array();
    foreach ($cart_decode as $key => $cart_item):
        $product = \App\Models\Product::where('id', $cart_item['product_id'])->first();
        $discount = ($product->price * $product->discount) / 100;
        $price_discount = $product->price - $discount;
    
        $total_cart[] = $price_discount * $cart_item['quantity'];
    endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it's working correctly